# Add call error message from controller in angular material?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-material

I want to add error message, something like this:

```
  <md-input-container>
    <label>Last Name</label>
    <input name="lastName" ng-model="lastName" required>
    <div ng-messages="userForm.lastName.$error" ng-show="userForm.lastName.$dirty">
      <div ng-message="required">Here is some message</div> 
    </div>
  </md-input-container>
```

But want to call rendering from controller:

```
callMessage() {
// How can I implement this?
}
```

Comment: Do you already have an Angular controller set up?

Comment: Yes. I have set up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are not using `controller as` syntax, so you will have to define a function on the `$scope` object within your controller:

```
function YourController($scope,...){

   $scope.callMessage = function(){
      //you can access your form using $scope.userForm
      return "yourString";
   }
}
```

Your markup would change as follows:

```
<md-input-container>
  <label>Last Name</label>
  <input name="lastName" ng-model="lastName" required>
  <div ng-messages="userForm.lastName.$error" ng-show="userForm.lastName.$dirty">
  <div ng-message="required">{{callMessage()}}</div> 
</div>
```

The important part is that you define your function on the `$scope` so that Angular actually can bind the `{{callMessage()}}` part in the markup to your function.

Answer (score 0):

You may do,

```
 <md-input-container>
  <label>Last Name</label>
  <input name="lastName" ng-model="lastName" required>
  <div ng-messages="userForm.lastName.$error" ng-show="vm.callMessage(userForm.lastName.$dirty)">
  <div ng-message="required">{{vm.myMessage}}</div> 
</div>
```

And from controller

```
callMessage(isDirty) {
 // Your conditional message with respect to "isDirty" parameter
 isDirty ? this.myMessage = 'Dirty Message' : false;
 return isDirty;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may call directly $error in your controller after you have set up form.

**View**

```
<md-input-container>
        <label>Last Name</label>
        <input name="lastName" ng-model="lastName" required>
        <div ng-messages="userForm.lastName.$error" ng-show="userForm.lastName.$dirty">
          <div ng-message="required">{{errorMsg}}</div> 
        </div>
      </md-input-container>
```

**Controller**

```
 var isError = $scope.userForm.lastName.$error;

 if (isError) {
    $scope.errorMsg = 'Hey, this is error message';
 }
```